# How to compare data from one response and another request in Soapui

Tags: xml, groovy, compare, soapui

So, HI everyone. It's my first time here and I would love to hear your answers.

Working in: SoapUI 4.6.1

I have WSDL with requests and i'm doing functional testing.
In my TestCase I need values from one request and different response to be compare and to be equal. Where can i do that and how?

I thought about "assertions" in request, but "Expected Result" is string and i can't input there data from another request.

So, to be sure you got everything right:
This is **one request(data inside is what we need)** which response with some data we don't need. Then come some another requests and after that comes request with response(data inside is what we need)

```
<soapenv:Envelope .....(there xmlns and scheme links)>
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ban:transactions>
<sessionid>xxx</sessionid>
<scheme_id>yyy</scheme_id>
<scheme_type>zzz</scheme_type>
 <field_list>

  <scheme_field>
   <field_id>aaa1</field_id>
   <type>bbb1</type>
   <value>ccc1</value>
  </scheme_field>

  <scheme_field>
   <field_id>aaa2</field_id>
   <type>bbb2</type>
   <value>ccc2</value>
  </scheme_field>

  <scheme_field>
   <field_id>aaa3</field_id>
   <type>bbb3</type>
   <value>ccc3</value>
  </scheme_field>
        ...
  <scheme_field>
   <field_id>aaaN</field_id>
   <type>bbbN</type>
   <value>cccN</value>
  </scheme_field>
</field_list>
</ban:transactions>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is response from another request(!):

```
<soapenv:Envelope .....(there xmlns and scheme links)>
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <data>
    <repeat>
    <next_scheme>
    <sessionid>xxx</sessionid>
    <scheme_id>yyy</scheme_id>
    <scheme_type>zzz</scheme_type>
     <field_list>

      <scheme_field>
       <field_id>aaa1</field_id>
       <type>bbb1</type>
       <value>ccc1</value>
      </scheme_field>

      <scheme_field>
       <field_id>aaa2</field_id>
       <type>bbb2</type>
       <value>ccc2</value>
      </scheme_field>

      <scheme_field>
       <field_id>aaa3</field_id>
       <type>bbb3</type>
       <value>ccc3</value>
      </scheme_field>
            ...
      <scheme_field>
       <field_id>aaaN</field_id>
       <type>bbbN</type>
       <value>cccN</value>
      </scheme_field>
    </field_list>
    </next_scheme>
    </repeat>
    </data>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to compare all this values - `xxx,yyy,zzz,aaaN,bbbN and cccN` from **first request** to all this values `xxx,yyy,zzz,aaaN,bbbN and cccN` from **response**! And if they are not equal - to pop-up a assertion or error.

Comment: Nikita, you mean to say that there is test step in a test case and you wan to compare the values in the response from the same request? or some other request? are they both in same test case? By the way, was it contain all the data? or trimmed data that you put in there?

Comment: Have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the groovy script which extracts each of the following and sort them and then compares the data.

- sessionid
- scheme_id
- scheme_type
- scheme_field

**Groovy Script**

```
//Pass the xml string for xml1 and xml2 
//Does not matter which xml you pass to which variable
//Not assigned here in the below to save the space.

def xml1 = 
def xml2 = 

//Closure to get the element data
def getData = { data, element -> data.'**'.findAll{it.name() == element} }

//Closure to sort criteria for scheme_field
def criteria = {a, b -> a.field_id.text() <=> b.field_id.text() ?: a.type.text() <=> b.type.text() ?: a.value.text() <=> b.value.text()}

def pXml1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml1)
def pXml2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml2)

//Extract the data from both xml element wise and sort data
def sessions1 = getData(pXml1, 'sessionid').sort()
def sessions2 = getData(pXml2, 'sessionid').sort()

def schemeIds1 = getData(pXml1, 'scheme_id').sort()
def schemeIds2 = getData(pXml2, 'scheme_id').sort()

def schemeTypes1 = getData(pXml1, 'scheme_type').sort()
def schemeTypes2 = getData(pXml2, 'scheme_type').sort()

def schemeFields1 = getData(pXml1, 'scheme_field').sort(criteria)
println schemeFields1
def schemeFields2 = getData(pXml2, 'scheme_field').sort(criteria)
println schemeFields2

//Now do the assertion of both xml data
assert sessions1 == sessions2
assert schemeIds1 == schemeIds2
assert schemeTypes1 == schemeTypes2
assert schemeFields1 == schemeFields2
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5206451228246016)</kbd>. Note that also, `scheme_field` order is changed in this demo to make sure that it can handle element list in any order.

Comment: Thank you Rao, i will try your method.
After i created this post, i found on one site a method:

<code>def xxx = context.expand('${Creation#request#//scheme_id}')
def yyy = context.expand('${Repeat#response#//scheme_id}')
assert xxx==yyy, testRunner.fail("Scheme_id is not equal")</code>

This worked perfectly, but i don't know - will this method somehow impact wrong in future? Create and Repeate here are test steps

Comment: The above handles in case the order of the schem_field is changed or not in sorted order.

Comment: Yes, in the Repeat it's like auto-sorted or something, i know which scheme_field[1], scheme_field[2] ... etc value is.

Comment: Have you tried the above solution? If that is helpful then see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: may sound stupid, but:
//pass the xml string for xm1 and xml2 
is it like <bla-bla>....</bla-bla>??
Because i tried 'def xml1=${create/request}' , which i used in my "try" and this doens't work...

Comment: @NikitaRysin, you should keep in mind that the solution is tied to the data / xmls that is provided in the question and does work if see the Demo provided above. Isn't it? If not tried suggest you to first try that one before comment irrelavant. If you have done modifications, then you should be able to modify the script accordingly or provide exact data is being used.

Comment: And you should clarify in detail what have you tried (possibly with exact data that you used), and what error do you notice?

Comment: I haven't changed anything, i just don't understand what you mean when you say - _//Pass the xml string for xml1 and xml2 _ 
How do i do that? Could you write an example? @Rao

Comment: Hope you can see [Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5206451228246016) link there in the above, click that and execute first to see where xml1, xml2 data is present and comparison is done or copy paste that script into a groovy script test step and execute it first to get the idea. If your problem is to assign dynamic xml from certain response? Then you need to provide how your test case is structured ? what steps and compare xmls of which steps?

Comment: yeah, i see now, sorry for my stupidness, didn't notice demo first time. But isn't it easier to use <code> context.expand('${}') to pass xml string?

Comment: Don't worry. You should be able to use as you need to work with the dynamic response / request what ever. Since I am the external user, and you provided the fixed xml's, I need to show the solution with the given fixed values. Hope you got what I mean. If you need to work with dynamic xmls, then provided the requested details of my earlier comment.

Comment: You can get the examples [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html) in order to use dynamic xml like you were trying to show in your previous comment.